# Error deploying the subgraph: Internal error: Could not pick index node

Tags: logs

I'm playing with ["The Graph"](https://thegraph.com/docs/deploy-a-subgraph#deploy-the-subgraph) example counter project. If all I do is change the contract address in the mapping.ts to the same Counter contract on Rinkeby, then try to deploy, I get this error:

```
Error deploying the subgraph: Internal error: Could not pick index node
```

My mapping.ts:

```
specVersion: 0.0.1
description: A simple counter
repository: https://github.com/graphprotocol/example-subgraph
schema:
  file: ./schema.graphql
dataSources:
  - kind: ethereum/contract
    name: Counter
    network: rinkeby
    source:
      address: '0xe740d90c98cbe1f23acdc0b65ac34750f6523b9b'
      abi: Counter
    mapping:
      kind: ethereum/events
      apiVersion: 0.0.1
      language: wasm/assemblyscript
      entities:
        - Counter
      abis:
        - name: Counter
          file: ./abis/Counter.abi
      eventHandlers:
        - event: Incremented(uint256,uint256)
          handler: handleIncremented
      file: ./src/mapping.ts
```